# What is the grammar of "the hope is..." versus "the hope is that"?

Tags: syntax

The sentence in question:

> But with the US leading by example, the hope is that international efforts to tackle global warming will be revitalised.
>
> [Source](https://www.bbc.com/news/world-us-canada-62457386)

I'm a non-native speaker. I understand that natives use "hope is" like this:

> With hard studying, hope is I will pass the test.

Please break this down grammatically for me to understand.
In my understanding, the sentence is grammatically wrong because
it should look like "A is B".
"A is B will C" is not an acceptable form.

I couldn't find any grammar rule pertaining to "hope is~".
Is there a "that" (relative pronoun) dropped somewhere?
Or does the word "hope" have some hidden grammar skillset/quality that most non-natives don't know about?

I think I found the grammar error first, then BBC had since updated the post.
(Proof :
https://hellotalk.com/m/uPyWJUS3OMuFDD==?id=L0pvNuN=)

Anyway, so even after BBC's update everybody here is saying that "that" can be omitted so I'm researching the conditions for omission of relative pronoun that.
BTW, if you guys could just name the concise and precise law of the grammar that allows for this, things would be simpler.
I had ran into another grammar question before,
and to understand this properly I had to be insistent in my pursuit.
(https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/513066/havent-we-vs-dont-we)

Just saying, contextually understood grammar technically isn't grammar. Grammar is rules and structures, not a literature piece.

That can be omitted when

1. it's pointing to an object (the girl (that) I love)
2. that after some emotional conviction words (I am glad that you came.)
3. after an attribution verb (Tom said that he didn't feel well.)
4. phrasal expressions (You may play provided that you do your homework first.)

Comment: Note that the phrase is "... *the* hope is"

Comment: _The hope is that..._ means _people in general hope that..._

Comment: "That" introduces a finite clause "international efforts to tackle global warming will be revitalised". Same as "He hopes that international efforts to tackle global warming will be revitalised." You might be better on English Language Learners because this type of clause is basic English grammar.

Comment: @StuartF Basic English teaches that after a verb of attribution(said, disclosed) can be omitted, not after plain be verb "is". So what's your mother language? You're welcome.

Comment: BBC correspondents love using phrases like **the hope /fear/belief/is** and leaving it to their audience to work out who is doing the hoping/fearing/believing.

Comment: @Vida: There is no error in the original sentence. It's _clearer_ with "that", but it's still _correct_ without. Note that "that" here is not a relative pronoun; it's a subordinating conjunction. It can always be omitted provided the sentence is still clear without it.

Comment: Isn't 'you're welcome' a passive-aggressive ending, and thus not welcome in comments?

Answer (score 5):

You are correct that "A is B will C" is not an acceptable form. However, that is not the form of the BBC sentence. The form is actually "A is B":

- A is the nominal phrase "the hope" (which functions as a subject).
- B is the nominal clause "that international efforts to tackle global warming will be revitalised" (which functions as a predicate nominative).

In the sample sentence that you wrote, the nominal clause "[[that]] I will pass the test" functions as a predicate nominative. As you realized, "that" has been omitted.

I'd encourage you to research nominal clauses if you're not familiar with them. (Some people also say "content clause", "that-clause", etc.)

By the way, "hope" requires a determiner, so you should say "the hope is . . .", "our hope is . . .", etc.:

> With hard studying, my hope is [[that]] I will pass the test."

Comment: 'That' can be omitted after a verb of attribution (said, stated, announced, disclosed) She said (that) she was tired.

Comment: [the most common verbs used for attributing human sources are “said,” “stated,” and “**asked**.”](https://ohiostate.pressbooks.pub/stratcommwriting/chapter/attribution/) But it would be a bit weird to omit ***that*** in, say, [***I ask that you support me***.](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=ask+you+support%2Cask+that+you+support&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cask%20you%20support%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cask%20that%20you%20support%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cask%20you%20support%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cask%20that%20you%20support%3B%2Cc0)

Answer (score 3):

"With hard studying, hope is I will pass the test" is a colloquial form that I would not say.

A fuller form of the same sentence is

> The hope is, I will pass the test.

or even more fully

> The hope is that I will pass the test.

This has the same structure as the relevant part of the sentence you are asking about.

(I would probably say "My hope is, I'll pass the test".)

Does that make it clear or is there something you still don't understand.